# function with many parameters - how to insert an argument

Tags: python

I would like to use a function with many parameters.

Is there a way, instead of having :

```
def fonction(ok):
    print("alors = %s" % (ok))
```

something like :

```
def fonction(question=ok):
    print("alors = %s" % (ok))
```

(but this code does not work)

I would just like to have the "question=" part to make things easier to read

Comment: question is unclear... What are yo trying to achieve? This function has only one parameter. Do you maybe mean a default value?

Comment: Apart from the fact that `question=ok` doesn't make any sense as a parameter, yes you can invoke parameters by name in Python.

Comment: Give it a try! The [python.org tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) is a good read.

Comment: It almost works. The default parameter "ok" needs to be defined before the function. If you meant to simply use the string "ok", then its `def fonction(qustion="ok")`. If you meant "ok" to be a variable, then put it before the function: `ok = "okay"`.

Comment: Posting the stack trace instead of "it doesn't work" is better. Then we can see what really went wrong. In this case it was likely something like `NameError: name 'ok' is not defined` but why should we have to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define things before you use them. If you meant `ok` to be a variable, then it needs to be defined before the function. Note that the function takes a reference to the object. If you rebind the variable later, that isn't seen by the function.

Then, notice that the variable name inside the function is the thing on the left, not the thing on the right.

```
# if you want the default to be a string
def fonction(question="ok"):
    print("alors = %s" % (question))

# if you want the default to be a variable
ok = "all is okay"
def fonction(question=ok):
    print("alors = %s" % (question))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to enter the type of variable as an argument

```
def fonction(question=str):
    print("alors = %s" % (question))
```